# Странный ответ regexp

Tags: java, snmp

Есть метод

```
   static boolean test(String regex,String testString){
    boolean normal=true;
    if (regex!=null){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
        normal=m.matches();
        System.out.println("regex "+regex);
        System.out.println("answer "+testString);
        System.out.println("result "+normal);
    }
    return normal;
}
```

И когда проверяю его в IDEA test("[0,3]","3"); то получаю true,но на сервере я получаю ответ по snmp и передаю его в этот метод, и получаю записи в бд и консоли:ответ-3,резултат-false,в чем может быть проблема?

UPD:как получаю ответ по SNMP (org.snmp4j):

```
    private String send(String oid) throws IOException {//snmp
    Target target = getTarget("udp:"+address.getNet_address()+"/161");
    PDU pdu = new PDU();
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(oid)));
    pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
    ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, target, null);
    if (event.getResponse() != null) {
        return event.getResponse().get(0).toString();
    } else {
        return "Timeout exceeded";
    }
}


  String s = send(pollDataSet.getOid());
  String answer;
  if (s.split("=").length == 2) {
     answer = s.split("=")[1].trim();
  } else {
     answer = s.split("=")[0];
  }
  boolean regexResult=test(pollDataSet.getNormal(), answer);
```

Comment: Часть кода, та где именно возникла проблема - отсутствует. Я не знаю как вам можно помочь.

Comment: А где вызов этого метода в представленном коде?